# Recover deleted file that is currently being written to

Tags: linux, filesystems, data-recovery, open-files, deleted-files

I started downloading a big file and accidently deleted it a while ago. I know how to get its current contents by `cp`ing `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` but since the download is still in progress it'll be incomplete at the time I copy it someplace else.

Can I somehow salvage the file right at the moment the download finishes but before the downloader closes the file and I lose it for good?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `tail` in follow mode should allow you to do what you want.

```
tail -n +0 -f /proc/<pid>/fd/<fd> > abc.deleted
```

I just did a quick test and it seems to work here. You did not mention whether your file was a binary file or not. My main concern is that it may not copy from the start of file but the -n +0 argument should do that even for binary files.

The tail command may not terminate at the end of the download so you will need to terminate it yourself.

Comment: Was about to post the same thing. Appears to work fine for binary files (`+1` works too).

Comment: Sometimes, we're happy doing really weird stuff

Answer (score 3):

Actually I had another thought. If you use another command to read `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` and keep that program running then when you download completes you can copy it from the appropriate `/proc/<pid2>/fd/<fd2>` file of the second command.

Just try

```
less /proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>
```

in a separate shell. Looking at the /proc entry for the less command should show you your deleted file.